How to calculate 2nd order perturbation theory of a Helium atom and beyond?
I have been interested in learning more about perturbation theory and came across this resource https://bohr.physics.berkeley.edu/classes/221/1112/notes/helium.pdf.
Where it goes through the first order perturbation theory for the Helium atom. However, in looking to extend beyond the first order, I am a bit lost. I found that the E(2) term is given by:
$$ E_n(\lambda)=E_n^{(0)}+\lambda \langle n^{(0)}|V|n^{(0)}\rangle +\lambda^2\sum_{k} \frac{|\langle k^{(0)}|V|n^{(0)} \rangle |^2}{E_n^{(0)}-E_k^{(0)}} $$
([from wikipedia] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_(quantum_mechanics))
What I am unsure about is the last term's denominator. The first link mentions that the electrons are not necessarily degenerate in Helium, but the same wave function is used for both of them. I was able to compute the first order energy as -2.75 like in the document, so I believe my calculations are correct. However, how am I able to get the different energies for the Helium atom if their wave functions and subsequent energies are taken as one expression and there is no stated numerical difference in the two energies?
The wikipedia page for the Helium atom describes its perturbation energy as:
$$ E_{n1,n2}=E_{n1}+E_{n2}=-\frac{kZ^2e^2}{2\alpha_0}\left[\frac{1}{n_1^2}+\frac{1}{n_2^2}\right] $$
However, there is no real description of the difference between $n_1$ and $n_2$
It says that the states described by their quantum numbers are unique, but it does not describe these values. Is $n_1=1$ and $n_2=2$ or am I missing something completely? Basically, how would I expand this into a second order perturbation?

The standard formula of PT does not apply to degenerate subspaces. In this case you have to diagonalize the perturbation operator in this subspace to obtain a nondegenerate basis. The keyword is degenerate perturbation theory. The equation  $E_{n1,n2}=...$ is not the perturbation energy. It is the zero order energy without the contribution of the perturbation operator term $H_1 = 1/|r_1-r_2|$.

Thank you for the information. Would that be the same line of thinking for the variational method as well?

I am not sure what you mean with same line of thinking. You may use the zero order ground state from PT as trial function in a variational calculation to obtain an upper bound for the true ground state energy by calculating the energy expectation value of the full Hamiltonian with this approximate state. This is done in the example on the wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variational_method_(quantum_mechanics), but that does not help you in your perturbation calculation and the energy is most likely a poor approximation.
